# Using Structures in VB.Net with Datatables

Tags: vb.net, datatables, structure

I recently came accross using structures in vb.net. So I was trying to make use of them to store tables of information, but I get an error saying the table is null. I assume this is because its not declared as a new instance, but structures don't accept "New".

Any ideas?

Heres what I use;

It crashes on this line: ds.Tables.Add(dt.AutoMatic)

```
Public Structure Reminder
    Public AutoMatic As DataTable
    Public Manual As DataTable
End Structure
Public Function ReturnReminders() As Reminder
    Dim DateRangeA As Date = Date.Today
    Dim DateRangeB As Date = Date.Today
    DateRangeA = DateRangeA.AddMonths(-1)
    DateRangeA = DateRangeA.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : DateRangeB = DateRangeB.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    Dim Sql As String = "SELECT reminder_id, Subject_Line, Body, LifeTime FROM ucert_reminder_tbl WHERE Date_Remind BETWEEN #" & DateRangeA & "# AND #" & DateRangeB & "# AND Hide = 0 AND AutoRem = 1" ' reminder_id = " & Id
    Dim Items As New ArrayList
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New Reminder

    ConOpen()
    ds.Tables.Add(dt.AutoMatic)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, _myConnection)
    da.Fill(dt.AutoMatic)
    ConClose()
    Return dt
```

Comment: Structures cannot be null, they always have a default value with all their fields initialized to something (except for fields of a class type, which is the only thing that can be null _inside_ it). It's something else that's causing the error. On what line is the error thrown?

Comment: The datatable is Nothing.  Though the point of that structure is mystifying - a collection or DataSet would be more appropriate.  Also, never ever concat strings for SQL use SQL parameters

Comment: ds.Tables.Add(dt.AutoMatic)
After ConOpen()

Comment: Besides everything @Plutonix mentioned, DataAdapters can open and close the connection themselves, so you can remove those ConOpen and ConClose lines.

Comment: ....but a local-only DataAdapter is a bit of a waste when `cmd.ExecuteReader` is all you need

Answer (score 0):

Visual Vincent was right,
Datatable was null.

Added this line

```
dt.AutoMatic = New DataTable
```

And now works fine.

Thanks for the all the help!
Defo look into Sql Parameters for future stuff